# How to link a Firebase Storage file to a Firebase Database entry?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I have users uploading files, and a Cloud Function responding by adding the uploaded file to the database, and planned on using the following path:

```
/files/{user-id}/{filename}
```

The reasoning being that if a file gets deleted, i can in the Cloud Function immediately get the reference to the database-reference.

However, i am not allowed to use certain characters in db-paths that are allowed in filenames (most specifically, a dot). How should this be set up, so that for a removed Storage-file I can immediately get the correct Database-path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `push()` the path under `/files/{uid}` to create the entry, then `orderByValue().equalTo(x)` to find the entry later for deletion.  This way, you won't have to worry about the contents of the file name.

Comment: Thanks, i must admit i hadn't looked into the query-ish options, since i thought nothing like that was available and everything had to be done with 1 path requests.